# PHP/AJAX do php when custom field has valid input WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Right now I am working on something that would make a user VAT exempt. I have set up a field that that requires a tax number(vat number). I have set up a php function that validates vat numbers `validate($vat_number)` that returns true or false.

**What I want**

Whenever the vat field is updated I want to validate if `validate($vat_number) == true`

If this is true I want to change the current customer to be vat exempt with the function `set_is_vat_exempt()` from WooCommerce.

When that has succeeded I want to use the AJAX `update_order_review` to set everything to VAT-exempt.

All this should happen without refreshing/reloading the page.

What should I do? I have decent knowledge of php and js, but AJAX is pretty new to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Facing a similar issue with trying to use AJAX to remove the tax.

Comment: Wish I did.. I should probably start learning AJAX :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a combination of AJAX and PHP to accomplish this.

The JS portion will have a validation function as follows:.

```
/*
 * Validates whether or not the necessary fields are provided.
 */
function validateExemptionStatus() {
    if ($("#wc_checkout_add_ons_3").is(':checked') && $("#wc_checkout_add_ons_4").val() != "" && $("#wc_checkout_add_ons_5").val() != "") {
        //Check the file upload
        if ($(".input-file-plupload a.file").attr("href") != "")
            return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

My particular use case has a file upload in there. You'll just want this to follow along with whatever you're looking to validate. I'm Using the WooCommerce Add-Ons plugin to handle additional fields. That plugin fires the *update_checkout* hook when you *focusout* from a field.

The AJAX code I have to handle the actual processing:

```
function handleTaxExemptionStatus(triggerUpdate) {
    //Validate whether all fields were filled out or not.
    if (validateExemptionStatus() === true) {
        var data_string = "action=example_remove_tax";
    } else {
        var data_string = "action=example_add_tax";
    }
    console.log(data_string);

    //Make the appropriate AJAX call to add/remove the tax.
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type:'POST',
        data: data_string,
        success: function(html) {
            if (triggerUpdate)
                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            console.log("ERROR:"+err.Message);
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

Now we're cookin'. We have the function to validate and the function that makes the actual AJAX call. Now we just need to know when to validate.

```
/*
 * When the AJAX call is complete, this function validates whether
 * or not the information for the tax exemption was changed.
 * If the information was changed, it makes a call to the handler
 * function to update the information (and the checkout data) accordingly.
 */
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    //Trigger when the order_review is updated
    if( settings.url.indexOf('update_order_review') > -1 ) {

        var validationStatus = validateExemptionStatus();
        var hiddenVarData = $("input#add-remove-tax-trigger").val();
        var hiddenVarValue = (hiddenVarData == 'true');

        if (hiddenVarValue != validationStatus) {
            //Set the new value on the hidden field
            $("input#add-remove-tax-trigger").val(validationStatus);

            //Update the exemption status
            handleTaxExemptionStatus(true);
        }

    }
});
```

Because the plugin wouldn't let me remove the events attached to the fields (I tried everything) -- I rely on a hidden field I created to determine when to tell WooCommerce when to update the order status. It's not ideal but it works.

Now -- the finishing touches. Wordpress needs to know what ajax_url is (you may see a JS error for this if you don't include this). I do this via:

```
/**
 * Adds the WordPress Ajax Library to the frontend.
 */
function add_ajax_library() {

    $html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $html .= 'var ajax_url = "' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '"';
    $html .= '</script>';

    echo $html; 

} // end add_ajax_library
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajax_library' );
```

Add this to your *functions.php* file and you're set. It will fire when WordPress bootstraps.

Now, the last piece. We need an internal function to handle the VAT adding/removal. This part is simple (thankfully):

```
function example_remove_tax_from_order(){ 
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_example_remove_tax', 'example_remove_tax_from_order');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_remove_tax', 'example_remove_tax_from_order');    // if user not logged in

function example_add_tax_to_order(){ 
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(false);

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_example_add_tax', 'example_add_tax_to_order');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_add_tax', 'example_add_tax_to_order');    // if user not logged in
```

Little complex but it works well. I searched all over and couldn't find a solution to this problem.